# Fortinet as intermediate router

Tags: firewall, fortinet, policy-routing

I have the next scenario:

FG1(LAN A)   **<--IPSEC-->**  FG2(LAN B)  **<--IPSEC-->** FG3(LAN C)

Basically I need that "LAN A" reach "LAN C" through FG2, I've tried with "router policy" and "router static" without success.

Thanks in advance to anyone can help me.

Comment: We need more information on your setup. What kind of firewalls/routers are in place, and what are the current routes that you have set up? Here's a good checklist to help you ask better questions: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question

Comment: Hi,

I have the next devices:

FG1 = Fortinet 40C
FG2 = Fortinet 40C
FG3 = Fortinet 30D

I haven't expertise with these devices, so I created a "simple routing policies" and his respective "firewall policies", that allow access between "LAN A, LAN B,LAN C" in both directions.

I tried to send the traffic from "LAN A" to "LAN C" using as gateway "ip adress LAN FG2", but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new tunnel FG1(LAN A)<--IPSEC-->FG3(LAN C). 
And create policy routes and IPv4 policies on both FGs.